# Custom Date deserializing: Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

i am trying to use the custom format for my date like this :

```
public class CustomDateMappingDeserialize extends JsonDeserializer<Date>{

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser paramJsonParser, DeserializationContext paramDeserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
         SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String date = paramJsonParser.getText();
            try {
                Date formattedDate= format.parse(date);
              return formattedDate;
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

    }

}
```

**Date is 2011-04-08 09:00:00**
 and after parsing i am getting the same date in FormattedDate and no exception.

is there something i am missing ?

Thanks

Comment: Printing the `formattedDate` show `Fri Apr 08 00:00:00 CEST 2011` for me. At midgnight as expected. What is the problem ? (I am surprise that this is working without the time pattern to be honest ;))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that the Object Date will always append a Time so if you want to cut it out you can convert it to a string like this:

```
String input = paramJsonParser.getText();
DateFormat inputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"); // this has to be like your input
Date date = inputFormatter.parse(input);

DateFormat outputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String output = outputFormatter.format(date); // Output : yyyy-MM-dd
```

Comment: `The thing is that the Object Date will always append a Time` With the SimpleDateFormat used (without time), this will not recover the value, so it will be `00:00:00`. So the date would be different. But the output is correct if this is what is asked

Comment: Indeed @AxelH, I personally don't favor loosing informations that might become usefull but I guessed that he wants it so I just posted it. The solution I use is a serializer to hide informations I don't want to see in the gui but keep all informations in the db. Could be a interesting thing for him too.